# For which $n>6$ is $11^{2^n} -2$ prime

Tags: prime-numbers

Inspired by [this answer to a cops-and-robbers code challenge](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/140858/58251)

The challenge was to create a program that gives one specific output for one single input number and another output for all others. The code checks that $11^{2^n}-2$ is prime and $n>6$, where $n$ is the input.

One answer is $n=18$. Are there any others?

Comment: $11^{2^{18}}-2$ is composite. Your link also mentions that it is the  solution but does not mean it is prime.

Comment: @pietfermat Thanks. That probably means the question makes no sense.